# Stuck on Boot After Changing Suspend Behavior 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, 22.04, suspend, power-management, battery

I'm new to Linux, I have dual-booted Ubuntu 22.04.3 on Dell XPS, and everything worked great, but I found out that the battery drain was too high on suspend mode. I found some articles and made the changes. Now when I try to wake up my laptop it is stuck on Dell logo, and I need to force it to power off and power on again.
These are the changes I made:

```
echo deep > /sys/power/mem_sleep

apt update
apt install sysfsutils
echo "power/mem_sleep = deep" > /etc/sysfs.d/99-deep-sleep.conf
```

cat /sys/power/mem_sleep is set to deep.
Thanks

Comment: There is no question in your post...